# getting text from file uploaded with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've got a very simple file upload for a text file using paperclip.

What I want to do is to get the first line of the text file and turn it into a hash I can search against in a database.

I don't think it makes much sense to save the file, then retrieve it, create the hash, and then save it again.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the text of the attached file before saving.

my controller is fairly simple at the moment

```
def create 
     @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
     @upload.user_id=current_user.id
    #get the first line of the uploaded file

   if @upload.save
      redirect_to @upload, :notice =>'Successfully uploaded file."
      else 
      render :action => 'new'
      end
end
```

Going through the documentation, I've seen that paperclip has a to_tempfile, which I assume I can read into a string, but i can't seem to find anywhere that shows me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `params[:upload]` is the `file_field_tag` in your form, then it's easier to bypass Paperclip and retrieve the first line of the file directly using Rails, just do this:

```
first_line = params[:upload].tempfile.readline
```

Comment: Jason, when you say 'bypass Paperclip', do you mean remove paperclip completely? I tried your solution (which seems to be exactly what I'm looking for), but I get undefined method 'tempfile' for #<Tempfile:... I don't have a file_field_tag per se as I'm using formtastic I have <%= semantic_form_for @upload... <%= f.inputs :file, so I would think I would need first_line = params[:upload]['file'].tempfile.readline

Comment: Based solely on your error, try just: `params[:upload].readline`  And by "bypass" I just meant not to use it for **this** - up to you whether you remove it, if this was all you were using it for then I'd say yes :)

Comment: Thanks Jason, I am using paperclip for more than just getting the first line, I do need to store the uploaded file, so I'll leave it there. But just in trying to get this to work, I tried the standard file_field_tag and then the code you provided with and without readline, unfortunately, I still get the same undefined method error.

Comment: ...and you went back and tried the params[:upload].tempfile.readline too?  It works for me, I tried it before recommending it.  You're not using Rails2 by any chance are you?

Comment: I'm using rails 3, I went back and tried it again with just tempfile, and with readline, but I get the undefined method 'tempfile' for {"file"=> "test_file.csv"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Comment: Ok, then `params[:upload]` is **not** your `file_field_tag` - you need to use: `params[:upload][:file]` instead, so: `first_line = params[:upload][:file].tempfile.readline`

Comment: after MANY MANY hours, I finally got this. the answer was just a bit off Jason, apparently I needed to use first_line=params[:upload].readline, without tempfile. Not sure why this is in my environment, and that is with paperclip. Once I got that working, I didn't try it again without paperclip. Thanks

Comment: That was precisely what I suggested in my first comment above :)  Glad to hear you got it working.